# SQL Analysis Services Component set to false?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssms

Our Database Server is undergoing an audit and they are requesting to set the Value of `Security\BuiltinAdminAreServerAdmins` to `false` from default value of `true`.

Now since it is a production server my worry is the effect of taking this action. Can anyone tell me the effect when I set it to `false`?

These are the steps to go on the said item:

1. Open the SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the  “Microsoft Analysis Server“
3. Right click on the “Microsoft Analysis Server“, then select properties
4. Tick the box for “Show Avanced (All) Properties“
5. Scroll down till you find  `[Security \ BuiltinAdminsAreServerAdmins]`  and check the current value
6. If the value set to true then stand on the true and change it to false

Thank you in advance. please see image as reference.

[image]

Comment: You might have better luck at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends whether you are relying on built in server admin groups to access to SSAS server or not. If not them you should indeed set this to false. Do you know how you defined your admin access to the SSAS server? In other words, who currently has admin access to the SSAS service?

Comment: Is it under the Security then Logins?